# Return last value of a column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get the last value of a record from the database. I am using entity framework. I am trying to get the last value of the balance and deduct the amount user enters to get the new balance. I am new to this and trying to create a simple expense management system.

My controller

```
      public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ExpenseId,ExpenseFor,DateTime,Amount,Balance,RowVersion")] Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {
            var a = db.Expenses.Select(b => b.Balance);
            var c = a.Last();
            expense.Balance = c - expense.Amount;

            db.Expenses.Add(expense);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(expense);
    }
        return View(expense);
    }
```

My model looks like this

```
public class Expense
    {
        public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
        public string ExpenseFor { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Balance { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to create new records, it says that the Method cannot be translated into a store expression. I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: try `var c = db.Expenses.Last().Balance;

Comment: You haven't posted any code that would cause that exception. That exception is raised when you attempt use a method in a query that EF doesn't know how to translate into SQL. For example, this could be a custom method on your entity or something like `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. However, there's nothing like that here.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the compiler points to    var c = a.Last(); that causes the exception.

Comment: Do you use SQL server, by any chance ?

Comment: `Last()` is simply what executes the query. There's something *before* that which is using an unsupported method in a where clause.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier yes i used SQL server

Comment: You cannot edit your question to show the correct code based on an answer (its not longer a question). I have rolled back the changes

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you . I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SQL server, it's no wonder `.Last()`function is not going to work.

There is no such things as (select last) in SQL server, so Entity basicaly fails to translate it to a database SQL server language. This is what you have to do :

```
var v = db.Expenses.OrderByDescending(t => t.ColumnName).First();
```

Or something similar, depending on what you want.

Try to think of a way to turn the query around and use `First()` ... or `FirstOrDefault()` if your are afraid of potential null values.

Your own solution :

```
var v = db.Expenses.OrderByDescending(t => t.ExpenseId).First();
```

Comment: The information you have provided is really useful. Thank you this worked. I had to make some changes but it works now.

Comment: @singha4086 You should not modify your question accordingly to the answer you found... Let the question containing the problem or no one will ever understand WHAT was problematic from the beginning... I will include your line in my answer